# Add multiple entries to mysql database through php form

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a database system to house and retrieve invoices for a retailer/ company. I'm looking for a way to add multiple entries to a mysql database through a php form without having to add each item individually. My form looks like;

```
<div class="new_invoice">
<form action="addCustomerInvoice.php" method = "post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<legend> Add new invoice for <?php echo $rsCustomer['forename']; echo ' '; echo $rsCustomer['surname']; ?></legend>
<h4>Invoice Number:</h4>
<input type="text" name="invoice_no">
<h4>Item Quantity:</h4>
<input type="text" name="quantity">
<h4>Item Name:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_name">
<h4>Item Category:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_category">
<h4>Manufacturer:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_manufacturer">
<h4>Item Description:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_description">
<h4>Item Price:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_price">
<h4>Item Information:</h4>
<input type="text" name="item_info">
<input type="submit" value="Add new record">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

And process like;

```
<?php
                            include 'database_conn.php';
                                $InvoiceNumber = $_POST['invoice_no']; 
                                $Quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
                                $ItemName = $_POST['item_name']; 
                                $ItemCat = $_POST['item_category'];
                                $ItemMan = $_POST['item_manufacturer']; 
                                $ItemDesc = $_POST['item_description'];
                                $ItemInfo = $_POST['item_info'];
                             $sql = "INSERT INTO hlinvoicetable (invoice_no, quantity, item_name, item_category, item_manufacturer, item_description, item_info) VALUES ('$InvoiceNo', '$Quantity', '$ItemName', '$ItemCat', '$ItemMan', '$ItemDesc', '$ItemInfo')";
                              $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
                            echo "New invoice added. 

                            mysqli_close($conn);
                            ?>
```

I'm wondering is there a way to repeat the form and have it add a new entry to the database unless fields are left blank and it is therefore ignored and no rows are added? Also could all items added hold the same primary key (invoice_no)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I don't say it, someone else will: don't `INSERT` unsanitized data.  Review secure code practices for PHP at [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/).  (In the case of mysqli, use prepared statements.)

Comment: You're correct I just wanted to strip the code down to try and keep it as simple as I could but your advice is well taken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use array names on your inputs. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="invoice_no[]">
...
<input type="text" name="invoice_no[]">
```

Then in PHP you would obtain the values from `$_POST['invoice_no'][0]`, `$_POST['invoice_no'][1]`, etc.

You could loop over the values, like:

```
foreach ($_POST['invoice_no'] as $key => $invoice) {
    if (!empty($_POST['invoice_no'][$key])
        && !empty($_POST['quantity'][$key])
        && !empty($_POST['item_name'][$key])
        //... include all fields that can't be left empty
    ) {
        // Do insert
    }
}
```

Also, as mentioned above, make sure to use bound parameters instead of putting user-supplied data directly into the SQL queries. It is really not much extra code and is necessary to save you from SQL injection attacks.